# company and user create in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to make a sign up form where you can create a user and a company at the same time. I have a user table and a company table.

user model

```
belongs_to :companies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
```

company model

```
has_many :users
```

users controller

```
def new
@users = User.new
@companies = Company.new
end

def create
@companies = Company.create(company_params)
@users = @companies.user.create(user_params)
@users.save
redirect_to :back
end

private
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
def company_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

Routes

```
resources :users
resources :companies
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.fields_for @companies do |build| %>
<%= build.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So this create a company and a user at the same time. But i want the user to be assigned a company_id there belongs to the company they just created. I have the company_id field in my users table. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

```
def create
@companies = Company.create(company_params)
c = Company.last
@users = c.users.create(user_params)
@users.save
redirect_to :back
end
```

I did add this to the user controller at it works, but it doesn't seems like the best solution. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do in the following way:

## Your User Model

```
belongs_to :companies,:inverse_of => :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
```

## Your controller

```
def new
  @users = User.new
  @users.build_company
end

def create
  @users = User.new(user_company_params)
  @users.save
end

def user_company_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, companies_attributes: name)
end
```

## Your View

```
<%= f.fields_for :companies do |build| %>
  <%= build.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

It works for me :)

Source: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html